# Preserve EXIF and rotate image in PHP

Tags: php, image, orientation, exif

My website is hosted on a shared hosting server (linux) and I don't think the GD imageRotate class is available to me.

What is the best way to rotate images based on EXIF orientation? This is current way I am trying but am getting `Call to undefined method resize::rotateImage()'

Thanks for your help

```
if ($exif['Orientation']){  
                                        $ort = $exif['Orientation'];                                            

                                        switch($ort)
                                            {
                                                case 1: // nothing
                                                break;

                                                case 2: // horizontal flip
                                                $resizeObj->flipImage($path,1);
                                                break;

                                                case 3: // 180 rotate left
                                                $resizeObj->rotateImage($path,180);
                                                break;

                                                case 4: // vertical flip
                                                $resizeObj->flipImage($path,2);
                                                break;

                                                case 5: // vertical flip + 90 rotate right
                                                $resizeObj->flipImage($path, 2);
                                                $resizeObj->rotateImage($path, -90);
                                                break;

                                                case 6: // 90 rotate right
                                                $resizeObj->rotateImage($path, -90);
                                                break;

                                                case 7: // horizontal flip + 90 rotate right
                                                $resizeObj->flipImage($path,1);    
                                                $resizeObj->rotateImage($path, -90);
                                                break;

                                                case 8:    // 90 rotate left
                                                $resizeObj->rotateImage($path, 90);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }

                    if (($resizeObj->width > 600) || ($resizeObj->height > 600)){

                        // *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
                    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(600, 600, 'auto');

                    // *** 3) Save image
                    $resizeObj -> saveImage($path, 95);

                }
```

Resize class

```
  # ========================================================================#
       #
       #  Author:    Jarrod Oberto
       #  Version:   1.0
       #  Date:      17-Jan-10
       #  Purpose:   Resizes and saves image
       #  Requires : Requires PHP5, GD library.
       #  Usage Example:
       #                     include("classes/resize_class.php");
       #                     $resizeObj = new resize('images/cars/large/input.jpg');
       #                     $resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
       #                     $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/cars/large/output.jpg', 100);
       #
       #
       # ========================================================================#


            Class resize
            {
                // *** Class variables
                private $image;
                public $width;
                public $height;
                private $imageResized;

                function __construct($fileName)
                {
                    // *** Open up the file
                    $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

                    // *** Get width and height
                    $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
                    $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
                }

                ## --------------------------------------------------------

                private function openImage($file)
                {
                    // *** Get extension
                    $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

                    switch($extension)
                    {
                        case '.jpg':
                        case '.jpeg':
                            $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                            break;
                        case '.gif':
                            $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                            break;
                        case '.png':
                            $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                            break;
                        default:
                            $img = false;
                            break;
                    }
                    return $img;
                }

                ## --------------------------------------------------------

                public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
                {
                    // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
                    $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

                    $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


                    // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
                    $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
                    imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


                    // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
                    if ($option == 'crop') {
                        $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                    }
                }

                ## --------------------------------------------------------

                private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
                {

                   switch ($option)
                    {
                        case 'exact':
                            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                            break;
                        case 'portrait':
                            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                            break;
                        case 'landscape':
                            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                            $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                            break;
                        case 'auto':
                            $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                            break;
                        case 'crop':
                            $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                            break;
                    }
                    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
                }

                ## --------------------------------------------------------

                private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
                {
                    $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
                    $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
                    return $newWidth;
                }

                private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
                {
                    $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
                    $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
                    return $newHeight;
                }

                private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
                {
                    if ($this->height < $this->width)
                    // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
                    {
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    }
                    elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
                    // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
                    {
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    }
                    else
                    // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
                    {
                        if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                            $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                        } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        } else {
                            // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        }
                    }

                    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
                }

                ## --------------------------------------------------------

                private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
                {

                    $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
                    $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

                    if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                        $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
                    } else {
                        $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
                    }

                    $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
                    $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

                    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
                }

                ## --------------------------------------------------------

                private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
                {
                    // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
                    $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
                    $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

                    $crop = $this->imageResized;
                    //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

                    // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
                    $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
                    imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
                }

                ## --------------------------------------------------------

                public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
                {
                    // *** Get extension
                    $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
                    $extension = strtolower($extension);

                    switch($extension)
                    {
                        case '.jpg':
                        case '.jpeg':
                            if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                                imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                            }
                            break;

                        case '.gif':
                            if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                                imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                            }
                            break;

                        case '.png':
                            // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                            $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                            // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                            $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                            if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                                 imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                            }
                            break;

                        // ... etc

                        default:
                            // *** No extension - No save.
                            break;
                    }

                    imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
                }


                ## --------------------------------------------------------

            }
    ?>
```